# Events lost when using Google Analytics for iOS SDK 2.0b3

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have recently implemented the Google Analytics `iOS SDK v2` into a number of `iOS apps`, and I have noticed that there are some seemingly large discrepancies in the reporting that is now being generated. My main concern is that the total event count for my tracking ID is about `50%` lower than what my internal metrics suggest it should be. I have spent some time trying to weed out possible issues.

First I thought I might not have been making the tracking calls to Google from within the app, but those all checked out. Next I tested the theory that the metrics weren't making it from the local database out over the network. After setting up wireshark to monitor the network traffic though, this too seemed to be working properly. Next I tried processing the events more slowly as I thought that it might have been the fact that events are fired in short time intervals that might be the problem. After slowing the event fire rate to at most 1 per second and then further to at most 1 per 3 seconds, I was still seeing a roughly `50%` event loss when monitoring my test sessions in the web UI. Also, it seemed somewhat random which events would be dropped in the reports that I generated.

Here is some other info about my analytics configuration:

- Dispatch interval of 60s
- Manually starting sessions
- Using multiple trackers

Strangely, the android versions of the same apps are not exhibiting the same issue.

If anyone has had similar experience or has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reaching out to the Google Analytics team, they confirmed that betas 3 and 4 of the iOS SDKs have a bug that is responsible for the underreporting that I'm seeing.

Comment: Is it possible that no events are firing properly under beta 4? I can see activity in the real-time pane which makes me believe I've properly wired up the base of the SDK but nothing is coming up in the events pane (this is even after waiting a 24hr period to see if it hadn't been processed by the events pane).

Comment: To be clear I am using the method "send:params:" on the GATracker protocol object.

Comment: How did you reach them? I couldn't find a contact url?? I was using beta 4 but none of the events are processed by Google since my update from old sdk (GANTracker) to GAI beta4

Answer (score 0):

On https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events there is info ( typo, Android -> Analitics):

> Note: The Google Android SDK for iOS may throttle events, as well as other hits, if a large number of send calls are made in a short period of time.

So, i think that Your problem can be related with this. If You're monitoring traffic by wireshark and Your app is sending proper calls, i think there is not much that You can do. Maybe, try to increase interval between calls to really undisputed value - like 30 seconds - and then count the difference.

Comment: I think the problem we're having (I am a co-worker of Jamie's) is that there is no indication of throttling. We're doing this exact same configuration on Android and not seeing any issues. We get all the events we'd expect and on larger scales are seeing almost 2x as many android events/session as iphone. Seems really fishy.