# Is there some events throttling in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to track several events in GA on page view (ga.js). So I'm trying to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name', 'action', 'description']);
}
```

Then I'm checking firebug network log and see that only 2 or 3 events were really sent. 
Then I'm setting breakpoint on this loop and go step by step with some intervals (3-5 seconds) and all requests were sent successfully.

Does anybody know is there some requests throttling for GA? I've found this: [Events lost when using Google Analytics for iOS SDK 2.0b3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248241/events-lost-when-using-google-analytics-for-ios-sdk-2-0b3#14401764)
But there is no such information in web-tracking section of the google analytics docs.

Comment: The workaround here is basically - go back to the drawing board and fire less events. Sounds like you're trying to use events when you should actually be using custom dimensions and/or ec.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are limits on client side and server side.

> ga.js:
>
> Each web property starts with 10 hits that are replenished at a rate
>   of 1 hit per second. Applies only to event type hits.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/limits-quotas

**analytics.js** (the newer gAnalytics library)

Each analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second. Applies to all hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).

Comment: Follow up to this: does anyone know – if or when one exceeds the rate limit, – is there is any way of knowing, either by notification or some section of the GA dashboard?

Answer (score -3):

Imagine you run this code:

```
while(1) {
   gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name', 'action', 'description']);
}
```

;) i'm pretty sure that guys at Google know how to handle that situations. There must be some kind of limit or protection on client side, even on server side. I'm thinking that GA script want let you run request in loop, and will count and control number of request per time unit. Also if you pass that, server should limit you by IP or some other kind of identification.

Comment: I understand that they must limit that. I just want to know what the limits and what are possible workarounds. First workaround is setTimeout, but I need to know what timeout will be safe for me and Google